# Where can I bring com.ms.* packages to build

Tags: java, applet, j++

I'm trying to build mS-java compatible applet and I have references to classes in com.ms.*.
But I can't find the required libraries.

Comment: Have I answered your question below? If so, I would appreciate you marking mine as the answer.

Answer (score 5):

They're part of the old Microsoft Java SDK, which is no longer available.

I think the only way to get your hands on the com.ms.* packages is by getting your hands on an old Microsoft J++ disc set. They don't sell those anymore, of course, but you can [find some on ebay](http://computers.shop.ebay.com/i.html?_nkw=microsoft+j%2B%2B&_sacat=58058&_trksid=p3286.m270.l1313&_odkw=microsoft+j%2B%2B&_osacat=0).

I would *strongly* recommend not using the J++ libraries, including com.ms.*. They're not supported, deprecated, and you won't find documentation online for them anymore. Also, there might be a questionable legality of using or selling software built with J++, given Microsoft's legal agreement with Sun to retire J++.

Comment: I looked it up through MS J++ files but never managed to find any cabs, jars, zips, classes that contain those libraries... it seems to be inside a dll.
So I don't know if there's a way to extract it from the dll.

Comment: A dll? Shouldn't be. I'm thinking they were in a jar file inside the Microsoft Java SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, which I am going to add here for posterity.  After much searching, I found this: http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=286826.  In short, the solution was to go look in the Windows registry to see what classpath Microsoft Java VM uses by default.  It turned out that the prize was hidden in `c:\WINNT\Java\Classes\classes.zip` (which you obviously include in the classpath like any other Jar).  When I added that zip file to my project classpath, all my com.ms.* dependencies were resolved!  Note that I already had `c:\WINNT\Java\Classes` in my classpath.

(@Judah Sometimes you have to work with legacy code and you have little choice but to use ancient libraries...)